# loading embedded resources which live in a different assembly

Tags: c#, resources, managed

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution which consists of an executable and a series of DLL projects.  All code is managed C# and running on Windows 10 64-bit.

One of the DLLs needs to load a resource specified by the application.  The app provides the full manifest resource path and the DLL uses this to load it.

The resources are set as "Embedded Resource" in solution explorer.  An example path would be something like "The.DLL.Assembly.subdir.resources.image.png".

The DLL uses the below code to load the resource.

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resStream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(path);
```

**This works great!  Well, that is if the resource in question is stored inside the DLL assembly which is trying to load it.**  We'd prefer, though, not to have to locate all the resources in this DLL assembly.  We'd like the freedom to let the application locate them in any of the projects and just provide the path letting the loading DLL know how to find them.  This would allow the app to better organize the resources based on which project "owns" them as opposed to being forced to put them all in the assembly which will actually load them.

Where I'm stuck is being able to load the resource if it lives in another assembly.

I've tried:

- GetEntryAssembly(), this returns the executable assembly, but loading the resource fails even with the full path, it appears GetManifestResourceStream() will only look in that assembly
- GetEntryAssembly().GetModules(), thinking I could somehow find the other assembly this way, but this returns a single entry, just the exe itself

Any ideas?  I'm thinking there must be a way to load an embedded resource which lives in another assembly, but I haven't yet found it.